# Make a text blink from a C console application

Tags: c

Hello I just got started with C and I don't know much about it, and I was wondering if it was possible to change the font/style/appearence of a text in a console application ?

Comment: It will depend on your console.

Comment: The `c` standard does not cover this, as far as I know, so it's going to be platform-specific.

Comment: if you are on linux environment, ncurses is a nice lib for that kind of stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change text color using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234508/change-text-color-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C has no concept of fonts, styles or other visual representational parameters. Unless you're writing a GUI application, you won't be able to specify anything like that.

Non-GUI application (console applications / CLI applications) that output text will do so by writing to `stdout` or `stderr`. The terminal/shell/console application that you're using will "intercept" these streams and display the content (eg. text) accordingly. Therefore, it's up to the terminal/shell/console to apply styling and you have to consult your terminal/shell/console documentation for that.

If you're writing text/terminal-based user interfaces you might want to look at libraries such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), if your console supports them.

You could also use higher level libraries, like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

(and you might consider writing a GUI application, using [GTK](https://gtk.org/)).

Notice that a [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/) or an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) or a Web server (e.g. with [lighttpd](https://lighttpd.net/)) can run a C software, and might not even have consoles, fonts, colors...